# No services for minikube windows "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Tags: windows, virtualbox, minikube

I have installed minikube via chocolatey on my windows 10 machine
I am using virtualbox for the VM
I have done `minikube start` and it is successful
Sporadically `minikube status` says that everything is running.
Usually, after I have started, the cluster is stopped.
I have disconnected from the VPN, restarted the computer, disconnected and reconnected to the internet, upgraded dropbox.
`minikube service list` returns either: 

`Get https://10.100.99.100:8443/api/v1/services: dial tcp 10.100.99.100:8443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Check that minikube is running and that you have specified the correct namespace (-n flag) if required.`

Or 

`|-----------|------------|--------------|
| NAMESPACE |    NAME    |     URL      |
|-----------|------------|--------------|
| default   | kubernetes | No node port |
|-----------|------------|--------------|`

I have started with multiple different commands:
`minikube start --vm-driver "virtualbox" --memory 8192 --disk-size 40g --host-only-cidr "10.100.99.1/24"` being the most recent.

I have deleted and removed all machine files and then used the start command again to recreate the machine.

I have updated my config.json file to ensure that all slashes are "windows" slashes

I am completely at a loss for how to get this thing running.

Comment: same thing here. I switched over from Hyper-v to virtualbox and I am getting sporadic disconnections now. I do not think this will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after my setup was running fine and I had to restart my Windows 7 machine.

1. Is your docker VM running as expected?

   - If not, $docker-machine stop default
   - Followed by $docker-machine start default
2. minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://$YOURPROXY:PORT \ --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://$YOURPROXY:PORT

Figure out if you are being blocked by a corporate proxy: https://superuser.com/questions/346372/how-do-i-know-what-proxy-server-im-using
The method using Chrome is the easiest